# Folder selector using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, file, export

I need to create a component in Reactjs which lets user select  a directory from his system. I tried using

input name="myFile" type="file"

it lets user select files. 
[I want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3w3v.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to upload the file?

if your target is that you can simply do it with any third party components which they already have written.

for files you can do this :

```
<input type="file" onChange={ (event) => this.handleChange(event.target.files) } />

handleChange(selected: FileList)
    {
        console.log(selected);
    }
```

Comment: NO I dont want to upload the file...I want to select the folder where I can save a file

Comment: do you try to add "webkitdirectory directory " attribute to your input? like this . <input type="file" webkitdirectory directory />

Comment: tried...it uploads all the files inside the folder...that's not what I need

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package for this [path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path)`npm i path`
This package is installed by default in node projects, this is used to read file extension, file basename and also we can use this to find the parent directory name (which you asked for) and much more we can do.

You can install this in react as well for reading Directory name [Check this method to read the Directory/folder name](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_path) or [Check this Site](https://flaviocopes.com/node-file-paths/)

**But you must give the file path**

Also, check Ant-design bootstrap to get access for file path easily [Ant-design component Link](https://ant.design/components/upload/) you can get the path in `onChange` function.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this same question today. Sadly, you can't for security reasons. There is a method called [showDirectoryPicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showDirectoryPicker) that may help you in this case, but it still can't give you the full path for the file. Best i could find with it was the name of the selected directory.